# How to select element im:name

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i'm trying to select a element im:something. I want to select it in my xsl file so i can show it when i browse my xml file. I've bees searching for a whole day to let this work. so please help mee.

here's the beginning of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\*\ItunesFilms.xsl"?>
<itunesfilms>
<feed xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en">
    <id>
https://itunes.apple.com/be/rss/topmovies/limit=10/genre=4401/xml
</id>
    <title>iTunes Store: Top Films in Action &amp; Adventure</title>
    <updated>2015-12-19T07:24:47-07:00</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="html_link"/>
    <link rel="self" href="html_link"/>
    <icon>html_link.ico</icon>
    <author>
        <name>iTunes Store</name>
        <uri>html_link</uri>
    </author>
    <rights>Copyright 2008 Apple Inc.</rights>
    <entry>
        <updated>2015-12-19T07:24:47-07:00</updated>
        <id im:id="1017058143">html_link</id>
        <title>
Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation - Christopher McQuarrie
</title>
        <summary>
Loaded with heart-pounding action and jaw-dropping stunts, prepare for the best Mission ever. With his elite organization shut down by the CIA, agent Ethan Hunt (Tom Cruise) and his team (Jeremy Renner, Simon Pegg, Ving Rhames) race against time to stop the rise of a new global threat, The Syndicate, a dangerous network of rogue operatives turned traitors. To stop them, Ethan must join forces with an elusive, disavowed agent (Rebecca Ferguson) who may or may not be on his side as he faces his most impossible mission yet.
</summary>
        <im:name>Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation</im:name>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="html_link"/>
        <im:contentType term="Movie" label="Films"/>
        <category im:id="4401" term="Action &amp;amp; Adventure" scheme="html_link" label="Action &amp; Adventure"/>
        <link title="Preview" rel="enclosure" type="video/x-m4v" href="html_link" im:assetType="preview">
            <im:duration>145657.0</im:duration>
        </link>
        <im:artist>Christopher McQuarrie</im:artist>
        <im:price amount="16.99000" currency="EUR">16,99 €</im:price>
        <im:rentalPrice amount="3.99000" currency="EUR">3,99 €</im:rentalPrice>
        <im:image height="60">html_link.jpg</im:image>
        <im:image height="60">html_link.jpg</im:image>
        <im:image height="170">html_link.jpg</im:image>
        <rights>© 2015 PARAMOUNT PICTURES. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</rights>
        <im:releaseDate label="31 July 2015">2015-07-31T00:00:00-07:00</im:releaseDate>
        <content type="html">
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr valign="top" align="left">
                                <td align="center" width="166" valign="top">
                                    <a href="html_link">
                                        <img border="0" alt="Christopher McQuarrie - Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation artwork" src="html_link.jpg"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td width="10">
                                    <img alt="" width="10" height="1" src="html_link"/>
                                </td>
                                <td width="95%">
                                    <b>
                                        <a href="html_link">Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation</a>
                                    </b>
                                    <br/> Christopher McQuarrie <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular">
                                        <br/>
                                        <b>Genre:</b>
                                        <a href="html_link">Action &amp;amp; Adventure</a>
                                        <br/>
                                        <b>Price:</b> 16,99 € <br/>
                                        <b>Rental Price:</b> 3,99 € <br/>
                                        <b>Release Date:</b> 31 July 2015 </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular">
                            <br/>Loaded with heart-pounding action and jaw-dropping stunts, prepare for the best Mission ever. With his elite organization shut down by the CIA, agent Ethan Hunt (Tom Cruise) and his team (Jeremy Renner, Simon Pegg, Ving Rhames) race against time to stop the rise of a new global threat, The Syndicate, a dangerous network of rogue operatives turned traitors. To stop them, Ethan must join forces with an elusive, disavowed agent (Rebecca Ferguson) who may or may not be on his side as he faces his most impossible mission yet.</font>
                        <br/>
                        <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular"> &amp#169; © 2015 PARAMOUNT PICTURES. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <updated>2015-12-19T07:24:47-07:00</updated>
        <id im:id="991367195">html_link</id>
        <title>Minions - Pierre Coffin &amp; Kyle Balda</title>
        <summary>
Since the dawn of time, Minions have served (and accidentally eliminated) history's most despicable villains. After their latest explosive mistake leaves them without an evil leader, the Minions fall into a deep depression. With the tribe on the brink of collapse, three unlikely heroes—Kevin, Stuart, and Bob—embark on a journey to find a new big boss. When their quest leads them to their next potential master, Scarlet Overkill (Academy Award® winner Sandra Bullock), our three heroes must face their biggest challenge yet: saving all of Minionkind… from annihilation!
</summary>
        <im:name>Minions</im:name>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="html_link"/>
        <im:contentType term="Movie" label="Films"/>
        <category im:id="4410" term="Kids &amp;amp; Family" scheme="html_link" label="Kids &amp;amp; Family"/>
        <link title="Preview" rel="enclosure" type="video/x-m4v" href="html_link.m4v" im:assetType="preview">
            <im:duration>164372.0</im:duration>
        </link>
        <im:artist>Pierre Coffin &amp; Kyle Balda</im:artist>
        <im:price amount="13.99000" currency="EUR">13,99 €</im:price>
        <im:rentalPrice amount="3.99000" currency="EUR">3,99 €</im:rentalPrice>
        <im:image height="60">html_link.jpg</im:image>
        <im:image height="60">html_link.jpg</im:image>
        <im:image height="170">html_link.jpg</im:image>
        <rights>© 2015 Universal Studios. All Rights Reserved.</rights>
        <im:releaseDate label="10 July 2015">2015-07-10T00:00:00-07:00</im:releaseDate>
        <content type="html">
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr valign="top" align="left">
                                <td align="center" width="166" valign="top">
                                    <a href="html_link">
                                        <img border="0" alt="Pierre Coffin &amp;amp; Kyle Balda - Minions artwork" src="html_link.jpg"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td width="10">
                                    <img alt="" width="10" height="1" src="html_link.gif"/>
                                </td>
                                <td width="95%">
                                    <b>
                                        <a href="html_link">Minions</a>
                                    </b>
                                    <br/> Pierre Coffin &amp; Kyle Balda <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular">
                                        <br/>
                                        <b>Genre:</b>
                                        <a href="html_link">Kids &amp; Family</a>
                                        <br/>
                                        <b>Price:</b> 13,99 € <br/>
                                        <b>Rental Price:</b> 3,99 € <br/>
                                        <b>Release Date:</b> 10 July 2015 </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular">
                            <br/>Since the dawn of time, Minions have served (and accidentally eliminated) history&amp;#39;s most despicable villains. After their latest explosive mistake leaves them without an evil leader, the Minions fall into a deep depression. With the tribe on the brink of collapse, three unlikely heroes—Kevin, Stuart, and Bob—embark on a journey to find a new big boss. When their quest leads them to their next potential master, Scarlet Overkill (Academy Award® winner Sandra Bullock), our three heroes must face their biggest challenge yet: saving all of Minionkind… from annihilation!</font>
                        <br/>
                        <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular"> &amp;amp;#169; © 2015 Universal Studios. All Rights Reserved.</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </content>
    </entry>
```

As you can see it is rss form itunes. As you can see int the xml file there are a lot of im:* elements. I want to know how to select them.

Here you can see my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<xsl:template match="itunesfilms" >
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:feed"/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="atom:feed">
<head>
<title>ItunesFIlms</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* some css */
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="kop">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/><small><xsl:value-of select="atom:rights"/></small></h1>
    <p>source: <xsl:value-of select="atom:id"/></p>
</div>
<div>
<table class="tg">
<xsl:for-each select="atom:entry">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l" colspan="5"><h4><xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/></h4><small><xsl:value-of select="atom:rights"/></small></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="4"><xsl:value-of select="atom:summary" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
        <img style="foto">
            <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="atom:link/@href [last()]"/></xsl:attribute>
        </img>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="atom:link/@href"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select='atom:im:name'/>
            </xsl:element>
        </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</div>
<xsl:for-each select="atom:entry">
<div class="con3">
<xsl:copy-of select="atom:content/node()" />
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Everything works expept `<xsl:value-of select='atom:im:name'/>`

When i browse this i get the error `Expected token 'eof' found ':'. atom:im-->:<--name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use two namespaces (`atom:im:name` combines two namespace prefixes). You have to declare the `im` namespace in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  ...  xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss"
```

After declaring the `im` prefix you can select the element `im:name` in XPath expressions. only use `im:name`, though, these are not elements from the `atom` namespace.